# Изменение фона и содержимого div при переключении страниц react router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Добрый день!

Есть компонент **header**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import cart from '../img/cart.png';
import SliderNav from '../components/sliding-menu'


const Header = () => (
    <header>
        <div className="nav-field">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-6">
                    <nav className="navbar-header">
                        <HashRouter>
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><Link to="/">Главная</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link to="/catalog">Каталог</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link to="/about_us">О нас</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link to="/news">Новости</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link to="/contacts">Контакты</Link></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </HashRouter>
                    </nav>
                    <div id="sliding-menu">
                        <SliderNav />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6">
                    <div className="register-box">
                        <div className="cart">
                            <HashRouter>
                                <Link to="/cart"><img src={cart} alt=""/></Link>
                            </HashRouter>
                        </div>
                        <div className="buttons" id="reg-buttons">

                                <button>вход</button>
                                <button>регистрация</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="header-circle">
            <p>авторские селекционные формы и сорта винограда</p>
        </div>
    </header>
);

export default Header;
```

являющийся частью **App**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Header from './components/header';
import Routes from './routes';
import Footer from './components/footer';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes />
        <Footer />
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

Есть **router**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Main from './pages/main'
import Catalog from './pages/catalog'
import About_us from './pages/about_us'
import NewsApp from './pages/news'
import Contacts from './pages/contacts'
import Cart from './pages/cart'
import LogIn from './pages/log_in'
import Registration from './pages/registration'


const Routes = () => (
    <HashRouter>
        <div className="main">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
            <Route path="/catalog" component={Catalog}/>
            <Route path="/about_us" component={About_us}/>
            <Route path="/news" component={NewsApp}/>
            <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
            <Route path="/cart" component={Cart}/>
            <Route path="/log_in" component={LogIn}/>
            <Route path="/registration" component={Registration}/>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

Задача такая. Нужно изменить фон компонента **header** при переключении страниц и удаление **div** `className="header-circle"` c заменой на нужный **div**.

вот вариант не на **react** [пример](https://denistolmachev.github.io/vine-store/index.html) хочу сделать так же используя **react** [пример](http://wine-store.pp.ua/#/)

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону Redux (диспатчера событий).
Создаете событие "Смена фона", в нем обновляете ваш store, в который будете ложить например bodyBackground. В Header пропишите background = bodyBackground. Затем при рендере какого-либо роута диспатчете событие "Смена фона".

Но есть и другой способ. Вынести Header и Footer в каждый компонент и в каждом месте передавать свое изображение(цвет фона)